# Why addition can't be performed while echoing concatenation in PHP

Tags: php, concatenation, echo, string-concatenation

Edit: Sorry, wasn't aware that this question was already answered.

Consider this php code:

```
<?php
$var1 = 10;
$var2 = 12;
echo "The addition of " . $var1 . " and " . $var2 . " is " . $var1 + $var2 . ".";
?>
```

The output of the above code is:

**12.**

But, while doing any other mathematical operation like multiplication or division like done below

```
<?php
$var1 = 10;
$var2 = 12;
echo "The addition of " . $var1 . " and " . $var2 . " is " . $var1 * $var2 . ".";
echo "<br>";
echo "The addition of " . $var1 . " and " . $var2 . " is " . $var1 / $var2 . ".";
?>
```

This time, the output comes like this:

**The addition of 10 and 12 is 120.


The addition of 10 and 12 is 0.83333333333333.**

Of course, keeping the operation in brackets solves this, but I'm curious to why it showed only "12."

Comment: The operators `* / %` have [a higher precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `+ - .`, so that part of the expression is evaluated first. As `+` and `.` have the same precedence, the expression is simply evaluated from left-to-right, meaning that you end up adding a string (which equates to zero) to **12**, then concatenating the full stop onto the end of the result.

Comment: If you turn on your error-reporting, you get: Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered on line 4 (you don't get this with / and *)